# Scheme - preventing a list's Items from functioning on definition

Tags: list, scheme, let

I'm having some trouble understanding something in scheme functionality, look at the following code:

```
(let
  ((a (list (< 10 30) (display "This message should never be printed"))))
  (not (car a)))
```

2 question rise up, 
A, why is it when I define a in this manner is the display function running even though I just want it to be an item in the list and not "trigger" it.
B, how do I prevent it from running?

Comment: What is `a` supposed to contain? The string "This ..." or a function that, when called, displays the string?

Comment: a just needs to be a list that its first Item is (< 10 30) and its second item is (display "This message should never be printed").

Comment: I think what I'm actually asking is if its possible to have it NOT evaluated while building the list , so I can use it later on by referring the first and second items in 'a'

Comment: Do you want to evaluate it later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent evaluation you need to quote:

```
(let ((a '((< 10 30) (display "This message should never be printed"))))
  (car a))

(let ((a '((< 10 30) (display "This message should never be printed"))))
  (cdr a))
```

yields

```
'(< 10 30)
'((display "This message should never be printed"))
```

If however you want to evaluate those expressions later, the easiest way is to wrap them into a lambda expression:

```
(define a 
  (list 
   (lambda () (< 10 30))
   (lambda () (displayln "This message should never be printed"))))

(first a)
=> #<procedure>

((first a))
=> #t

(second a)
=> #<procedure>

((second a))
=> This message should never be printed
```